# Polymer Starter Kit vs Polymer App Toolbox

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit, progressive-web-apps, polymer-cli

What's the difference between [Polymer Starter Kit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/) and [Polymer App Toolbox](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/)?

Both are collections of web components, build & testing tools, and Material Design templates for building Progressive Web Apps with Polymer.

Which one should I base my new project on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some details regarding both of them:

### Toolbox

**Pros:**

- Was built after Polymer team started focusing on app side of Polymer
  rather than elements
- Gets more updates than PSK
- Has all the other required tools (server, linter, bower, tester)
  built-in
- In case of building an element (like to publish) it uses flat import
  structure, where even though `bower downloads` are kept in
  `bower_components` folder and element to be made is kept outside the
  `bower_components` folder imports are still made as though both are
  present in `bower_components`
- Is made specifically to help developers in building their
  application/element
- Is more in line with Progressive Web app vision of the team.

**Cons:**

Still in beta phase just like all the `app-elements` it uses internally

### PSK

PSK was built with the purpose of providing a starting point for the developers who are new to `Polymer` and are more in learning phase. It has some pre-built elements with hard-coded data. If you look inside `index.html` you will find `<template is="dom-bind">` being used which `Polymer` team recommends not to use in production environment. It was built when `Polymer` team was still focusing more on the elements side of `Polymer` as a result it does not use any of the `Polymer's` `app-elements` using which Polymer team has built the `shop demo`. A newer version has not been released since March as team is currently working on version 2 of PSK.

Comment: Actually, PSK was last updated on [June 7, 2016](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/commits/master) and the PSK2 branch is under [active development](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/commits/psk2-polymer-build).

Comment: @niutech You are right. Actually the last release was in [March](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/releases). I've made a correction in the answer and have also included the detail that you pointed out.

Comment: The note about the Polymer team recommending "not to use [`dom-bind`] in production environment" is false.

Comment: @tony19 I think it was in one of the `Polycasts` video where they said that here we are using `dom-bind` but in production always prefer creating a new element rather than using `dom-bind`.

Comment: @a1626 Do you have a link to that Polycast or any official reference? There's no such warning in the [docs for `dom-bind`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/dom-bind), and I doubt it's actually true.

Comment: @tony19 let me search for it, might take a little time though

Comment: @a1626 Thanks. I'd like to get to the bottom of it :)

Answer (score 7):

The official Polymer blog post [Should I Use Polymer Starter Kit or Polymer CLI](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/blog/2016-08-18-polymer-starter-kit-or-polymer-cli) states that **if you’re starting a new project, use Polymer CLI** (which is a part of Polymer App Toolbox). In fact, the Polymer Starter Toolkit 2 is just another template that you can use with Polymer CLI:

[image: Polymer CLI]